# Check stock status at a retailer

Tags: python, beginner

I am learning Python and wrote this code to check (every 10 mins) whether a product is available at a retailer, since it usually runs out of stock pretty quickly. It's working as expected, but can someone provide feedback if this makes sense or how to write it best?

```
import time
import requests
from datetime import datetime

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/XXXXXX.mailgun.org/messages",
        auth=("api", "XXXXXXX"),
        data={"from": "Birks Alert <abc@gmail.com>",
            "to": ["abc@gmail.com"],
            "subject": "Birkenstock In Stock @ Costco",
            "text": "Birks in stock now!!!"})

while(True):
  url = 'https://www.costco.ca/birkenstock-arizona-birko-flor-sandal.product.100532624.html'
  header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.76 Safari/537.36', "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1","DNT": "1","Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8","Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5","Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate"}
  response = requests.get(url, headers=header)
  str = response.content
  now = datetime.now()
  if str.find(b"Page not found")!=-1:
    print("Product Out of Stock at", now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

  else:
    print("Product in Stock at", now.strftime("%H:%M:%S"), "....sending email now!!!")
    send_simple_message()

  time.sleep(600)
```

Answer (score 7):

- You don't need to search the content of the page for the string "Page not found" if the HTTP response already gives you the `404 Not Found` status code. I would change the logic a little so that a `200 OK` response corresponds to the product being in stock, a `404 Not Found` response means the product is out of stock, and a `5XX` response can be logged as a special case where the site might be down:

  ```python
  response = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

  if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:  # 200 OK
      print("in stock")
  elif response.status_code == requests.codes.not_found:  # 404 Not Found
      print("out of stock")
  elif response.status_code >= 500 and response.status_code <= 599:  # 5XX
      print("got a 5XX, site might be down")
  else:
      print(f"got unexpected HTTP status code: {response.status_code}")
  ```
- Instead of running the script in an infinite loop with a 10 minute sleep, I'd recommend removing the loop (and sleep statement) and using a job/task scheduler like `cron` to run the script once every 10 minutes.
- One suggestion to improve the user experience: once you determine that the product is in stock, include its product URL in the body of the e-mail so the recipient can easily visit it and verify if the product really is in stock or not. This guards against a possible false positive, for example, imagine if Costco changed their website so that visiting a page for an out-of-stock product now returns a `200 OK` response, but the page now shows an "out of stock" message.

---

Side note: I saw that you did something like `response.content.find(b"Page not found")!=-1` to perform a text search because `response.content` returns the response as raw bytes. Instead of doing that, you can just inspect `response.text` which is the text response, and do `"Page not found" in response.text` to check for the existence of the string "Page not found" in the response text.